# Resource that provides number of documents where the term is covered

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp, corpus

I am looking for resources that provides the number of documents a term is covered in. For example, there is about 25 billion documents that contains the term "the" in the indexed internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any document frequency lists for large corpora such as the web, but there are some term frequency lists available. For example, there are the [frequency lists from the web corpora compiled by the Web-As-Corpus Kool Yinitiative](http://wacky.sslmit.unibo.it/doku.php?id=frequency_lists), which include the 2-billion ukWaC English web corpus. Alternatively, there are the [n-grams from the Google Books Corpus](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html).

It [has been shown](http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.3755) that such term frequency counts can be used to reliably approximate document frequency counts.

Comment: Thank you, your pointers helped out. However, downloading large files especially from Google, crashed my computer. Hahaha

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/bncfreq/flists.html) is a little more treatable frequencies.

Also take a look at [this site](http://corpus.byu.edu/) - it contains a lot of info about existing corpora and words/ngrams lists. Unfortunately, most resources are paid, but not n-grams (for n > 1), so if you're going to process multiword terms, it can help.